# How can I define a Stream with a "throw exception" value?

Tags: scala, types, lazy-evaluation

I wanted to define a `Stream` that throws an error when the second element is accessed (for testing). This does compile &work:

```
val t: Stream = Stream(1, () => throw new AssertionError() ,1)
```

However it's not great as this doesn't compile:

```
val t: Stream[Int] = Stream(1, () => throw new AssertionError() ,1)
```

How could I make it work for `Stream[Int]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define such a stream like this:

```
def s: Stream[Int] = 1 #:: { throw new Exception } #:: s

scala> s.head
res1: Int = 1

scala> s.tail
java.lang.Exception
    at $anonfun$s$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at $anonfun$s$1.apply(<console>:7)
```

`#::` is the stream version of `Cons` or `::`, so what this does is creating a stream that contains `1` as first element, throws an exception when accessing the second element and then recurses on itself.